# multiple radial-progress charts (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, progress-bar, progress

I'm attempting to recreate and update this [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aeIAL). I was able to create a separate chart but unable to achieve the second progress.

> The second chart

```
<div id="radial-progress-vha">
            <div class="circle-vha">
            <div class="mask-vha full-vha">
            <div class="fill-vha"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mask-vha half-vha">
            <div class="fill-vha"></div>
            <div class="fill-vha fix-vha"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="shadow-vha"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="inset-vha">
            <div class="percentage-vha">22.17</div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

My understanding is that each graph should be unique therefore I copied the original css with a different name. This is [where](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazmemon/2sapcop7/3/) it fell apart.

> The js

```
var transform_styles = ['-webkit-transform', '-ms-transform', 'transform'];
window.randomize = function() {
var rotation = Math.floor((180)*.123);
var fix_rotation = rotation;
for(i in transform_styles) {
    $('.circle .fill, .circle .mask.full').css(transform_styles[i],'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)');
//$('.circle .mask.left').css(transform_styles[i], 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)');
$('.circle .fill.fix').css(transform_styles[i],'rotate(' + fix_rotation + 'deg)');
}
}
setTimeout(window.randomize, 200);
$('#radial-progress-vha');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uouxcLbd/

Your main issues were

- you didn't need to duplicate the definition of `transform-styles`
- The `$('#radial-progress-va');` and `$('#radial-progress-vha');` lines were unnecessary
- The second definition of `window.randomize` needed a different name
- The second `randomize` function needed to use your css classes with the `-vha` suffix
- You made a typo in the CSS - it was missing a single `.` so the `.fill-vha` selector didn't work

Comment: No worries, would be great if you could accept the answer, maybe upvote it too :)